# Jquery: Need help with the logic. Different divs, each w/ their own trigger. Only one can be open at a time, close all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, slidedown

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/ZSvHK/

I need help figuring out how to get this right, problems listed below. If you could suggest any improvements, that'd be great.

I have multiple divs, each div has it's own trigger(button).
Only one menu can be open at a time, so if I have **`DIV1`** shown, and I click the trigger for **`DIV2`**: then **`DIV1`** should close, and **`DIV2`** should open.

If the DIV is being animated when I click the trigger(button), then don't do anything, to keep from queuing up and having other problems.

If the DIV is open and I click on anything outside of the DIV, the DIV closes, which is correct behavior. Check out the example.

### My problem:

1. is that if I have **`DIV2`** open,
   and I click the the trigger(button)
   for **`DIV1`**, **`DIV2`** doesn't
   close like it should.
2. When double clicking the button(when
   DIV is hidden, click, then while
   it's still animating click again)
   the DIV SlidesDown like it's
   supposed to, but then it slidesUp.
   The button shouldn't accept anything
   while the DIV is animating, AKA I
   don't want it to queue like that.
   And in the future I wont be using a
   button for the trigger, so disabling
   wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to add a proper id for each button:

```
<button rel="search" id="searchButtonId">click</button>
```

Then, you can bind the click event for the buttons and check which one has been clicked on:

```
$("button").click(
    function() {
        if ( $(this).is("#searchButtonId") ) {
            $("#search").slideDown(800);
            $("#bottom").slideUp(800);
        } else if( $(this).is("#bottomButtonId") ) {
            $("#search").slideUp(800);
            $("#bottom").slideDown(800);
        }
    }
);
```

But, with this solution the divs are not closed if you click somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like an accordion to me : http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

You can close all divs before open one. Something like this (with variation)
$('.mydivs').hide();
$('.mydivs.div1').show();